# iOS - Making CATextLayer scrollable

Tags: ios, text, scroll, layer, catextlayer

I would like to make this text within a layer scrollable. I am currently able to display the following text on a image. However in case the text is too long a part of it does not show up. Therefore I would like to vertically scroll it. Not very familiar with scrollView object. Could anyone help out?

```
// Create the new layer object
boxLayer = [[CATextLayer alloc] init];

// Give it a size
[boxLayer setBounds:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 500.0, 500.0)];

// Give it a location
[boxLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(300.0, 350.0)];

// Make half-transparent red the background color for the layer
UIColor *reddish = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.1];

// Get CGColor object with the same color values
CGColorRef cgReddish = [reddish CGColor];
[boxLayer setBackgroundColor:cgReddish];

// Make it a sublayer on the view's layer
[self.view.layer addSublayer:boxLayer];

// Create string
NSString *text2 = @"The article was about employment.\nHe leafed through it in an instant.\nHis feeling of anxiety resurfaced and he closed the magazine.\n\n-Hm…, he breathed.\n\n-Have you been looking for work long?, asked the stranger at his side.\nThe article was about employment.\nHe leafed through it in an instant.\nHis feeling of anxiety resurfaced and he closed the magazine.\n\n-Hm…, he breathed.\n\n-Have you been looking for work long?, asked the stranger at his side.\nThe article was about employment.\nHe leafed through it in an instant.\nHis feeling of anxiety resurfaced and he closed the magazine.\n\n-Hm…, he breathed.\n\n-Have you been looking for work long?, asked the stranger at his side.";

// Set font
[boxLayer setFont:@"MarkerFelt-Thin"];

// Set font size
[boxLayer setFontSize:20.0];

[boxLayer setAlignmentMode:kCAAlignmentLeft];

boxLayer.wrapped = YES;

// Assign string to layer
[boxLayer setString:text2];
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473646/how-can-i-make-my-catextlayer-object-scrollable-like-uitextview or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198084/resize-catextlayer-to-fit-text-on-ios

Comment: Rachel. I knew about the first link you provided but it did not help. I'm going to check the second one but if you have a simple solution feel free to post it...

Answer (score 0):

You can not scroll CATextLayer directly.
First you have to add CATextLayer inside UIView than add the UIView inside ScrollView.
Now you can scroll CATextLayer.
Please tell me if it work for you.